# Call to a member function socials() on null

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have followings migration in laravel:

```
    Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->longText('about_us');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('email');

        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('socials', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('link');
        $table->integer('setting_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('setting_id')
            ->references('id')->on('settings')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

And inside Setting model I have hasMany relationship:

```
 public function socials()
{
    $this->hasMany(Social::class,'setting_id');
}
```

In my controller, I am doing this:

```
    $settings = new Setting();
    $settings->about_us = $request->get('about_us');
    $settings->email = $request->get('email');
    $settings->phone = $request->get('phone');
    $settings->save();
    $settings->socials()->saveMany([
        $this->make_socials($request, 'facebook'),
        $this->make_socials($request, 'linkedin'),
        $this->make_socials($request, 'instagram')
    ]);
    return responder()->success($settings)->respond('200');
}
```

what I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `return` in relation method.

```
public function socials()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Social::class,'setting_id');
}
```

Comment: my bad, sorry for this question))

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'setting_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `socials` (`title`, `link`, `setting_id`,)

Comment: I am getting this

Comment: should not  with saveMany set automatically setting_id?

Comment: I think it should set automatically. It has `setting_id` in query, it could means that `id` was setted, but `null`. Use `dd($settings)` before save relation, check that `$settings` has filled `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Make this nullable.Because in this case when you don't set a value to setting_id then it give you an error.Because it not nullable.Make it nullable

```
$table->integer('setting_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

then

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```